# Neural Network For a Non-Linear Function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to find an appropriate neural network structure to learn a function of the following form: F(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)= a*x1+b*(x2-x4)/(x3-x4) + c*x5.

I am using the matlab's neural network toolbox to create a feedforwardnet, but without any luck.

Is it even possible to learn this kind of function using a neural network? 
If yes, what can be an appropriate structure? 
If no, are there any other models that can learn this kind of function?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, can I use something else, but NN to build an expert for this kind of function?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you start by preparing a training dataset in which you have the following:

1- Dataset

x1, x6, x5; x6 = (x2 - x4) / (x3 - x4)

2- Target label Y

Y = f(x1, x6, x5); you may assume some values of a,b,c

So, you have 3 input variables or features with one target variable Y.

Then, you define the ANN to have only one single layer (single layer Perceptron) and make sure that the output function is linear.

Finally, train the ANN and give it new values in terms of x1, x5 & x6 and compare
with the actual function.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was planing to do.

Comment: Note that this answer is exactly identical to mine: a single-layer Perceptron is linear regression.

Comment: Not exactly. A single layer perceptron with a sigmod activation function is not a linear regression model. So, the output function should be linear which is not clarified in your answer. Also, you did not mention the training part in you post.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to estimate the values of a, b, and c. Although the function is not linear with respect to its input, it is linear with respect to a, b, and c. So you should be able to solve your problem with linear regression.

More precisely, if you define x6 = (x2 - x4) / (x3 - x4), then you get F(x1, x5, x6) = a * x1 + b * x6 + c * x5, which is linear.

Comment: You didn't understand correctly. For a given a,b,c and I want to create a neural network that will predict F.

Comment: @fudge Then your notation of F(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) is misleading.